# Check if the end of one string matches the begining of another string

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I have two strings:

```
let string1 = "Some text here";
let string2 = "text here as well";
```

I would like to check if the end part of `string1` matche the start of `string2`.

I'm outputting `string1 + string2`. In my case I don't want to print the same words twice. For example, I don't want to print `"Some text heretext here as well"`.

How to I check for this? I have tried `startsWith`/`endsWith` and a loop by spiting the string from space. But i don't think my approach is correct as the matching part of strings can vary in length.

Strings can also contain dashes. For example it can be like:

```
let string1 = "Some-text here";
let string2 = "text here as well";
```

In the above example the ideal output will be `"Some-text here as well"`.

Comment: What if the sting one maches but without dashes, eg let string1 = "Sometext here"; let string1 = "Some-text here"; what should be the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get substrings of both input values, from the end of `string1` and the start of `string2`. If these are the same, we've found our overlap.

```js
let string1 = "Some-text here";
let string2 = "text here as well";

let overlap = null;
for(let i = 1; i <= string1.length; i++) {
     if (string1.substring(string1.length - i) === string2.substring(0, i)) {
         overlap = string2.substring(0, i);
         break;
     }
}

console.log('Overlap:', overlap);

let concatenated = string1.replace(overlap, '') + string2;

console.log('string1 + string2:',concatenated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible brute-force solution:

```
let resultIdx = 0;
for (let idx = 0; idx < Math.min(string1.length, string2.length); idx++) {
    if (string2.substring(0, idx) === string1.substring(string1.length - idx)) {  
      resultIdx = idx
    }
 }
let result = string1 + string2.substring(resultIdx)
```

We loop over the strings and check if any substrings match. If so, we save the last index and use it to build the solution (saved in variable `result`). Is this what you want to find?

Answer (score -1):

```js
let string1 = "Some-text here";
let string2 = "text here as well";
let splitString1 = string1.split(" ");
let splitString2 = string2.split(" ");
let stringSet1 = new Set(splitString1);
let stringSet2 = new Set(splitString2);

console.log(stringSet1);
console.log(stringSet2);

function wordDiff(strSet1, strSet2) {
  let _wordDiff = new Set(stringSet1);
  
  for (let elem of stringSet2) {
    if (_wordDiff.has(elem)) {} else {
      _wordDiff.add(elem);
    }
  }
  
  return _wordDiff;
}

let result = wordDiff(stringSet1, stringSet2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The result is incorrect: `Set { "Some-text", "here", "text", "as", "well" }` instead of `"Some-text here as well"`. Also, using Sets is incorrect. Words should be able to repeat in a sentence; the repetition should just not be consecutive at the point where both strings meet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).